# Pandoc: multiple footnotes next to one another?

Tags: latex, pandoc, pdflatex

If I want to have two footnotes cited next to one another, separated by a comma, what is the syntax for doing so? The [Pandoc documentation](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html) doesn't seem to specify how.

As an example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

`Some text here [^fn1, ^fn2]  ## this clearly isn't the syntax, I've tried this.`

becomes:

> Some text here <sup>1, 2</sup>.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The syntax for multiple footnotes would be:

```
Some text here [^fn1][^fn2]

[^fn1]: foo
[^fn2]: bar
```

However, to separate them by comma in PDF output, you'll have to [tell LaTeX to do so](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28465/multiple-footnotes-at-one-point) by including the following in your [pandoc template](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#templates):

```
\usepackage[multiple]{footmisc}
```

For HTML output, you'd have to to something similar in CSS:

```
<style>
.footnote-ref ~ .footnote-ref :before {
  content: ', '
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks! In case others end up here to find that .footnoteRef does not have any effect, in my case .footnote-ref did the trick.

Comment: thanks @pataIt, indeed the class is `footnoteRef` in older pandoc versions and `footnote-ref` in newer versions (I updated it in the answer)

Answer (score 0):

The [answer by mb21](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40091457/10871073) is output-specific and the CSS provided will include the comma in the anchor tag (so it will be part of the link).

An alternative would be to modify the AST with a lua script:

```lua
list = false

local filter = {
  traverse = 'topdown',

  Note = function (n)
    if list then
      n = pandoc.Span({ pandoc.Superscript(pandoc.Str ", "), n }, {class = "footnote-ref-wrapper"})
    end
    list = true
    return n,
      false -- stop traversal here
  end,

  Para, Str, Space = function (i)
    list = false
    return i
  end
}
return {filter}
```

This can be used as follows, where the file `script.lua` contains the provided script:

```bash
$ pandoc <input file> -o <output file> --lua-filter=script.lua
```